# How to determine maximum number of User allowed in Office 365 Plan 1?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, licensing, azure-ad

I subscribe to SharePoint Online Plan 1 as shown [here](https://products.office.com/en-au/sharepoint/compare-sharepoint-plans). It says $7.00 per user.

I added more than 500 users from office 365 admin and shared my SharePoint Online site with them and it worked.

So I am confused that will I be charged additional amount from Microsoft?

I have not assigned any license to the new user while creating them.

Additionally I want to know that what is the major difference between licensed user using the site and unlicensed user using the site?

Any documentation or reference link is most welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say this is area which MSFT keep open. There is no way to restrict user without licensing to access the site. But it is customer responsibility to make sure that all the user who access the SPO should be assigned proper licensing.

When MSFT will do the auditing on your tenant then they will come to know about it and you have to pay the price. You are responsible for it, i think in Auditing you can atleast check the user with licensing( not sure). Check this https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Search-the-audit-log-in-the-Office-365-Security-Compliance-Center-0d4d0f35-390b-4518-800e-0c7ec95e946c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

Comment: I was having the same confusion, Thanks for clarification. You saved me from the huge bills.....